# An rendered image containing emissions particles, when zoomed in get's very pixelated

Tags: rendering, particles, image, lighting, system

So I have created a Christmas scene where there are houses and particles all around the house which is made by particle systems and emission.

When I render it and zoom the pic all the particles are very pixelated. I have tried to add denoising and all stuff but the issues is same. Do I have to increase the sample scene for a beautiful emissive scene?

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify the title and the text. Also, please use punctuation, commas and periods to make it more legible.

Comment: Hello :). Please add an example of your render, your render resolution and sample count.